# Regex, stop ".*" matching

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a simple regex but I am having some difficulties with something:

Let's imagine the following text:

```
<div class="thread">things</p></div><div class="thread">things</p></div>
<div class="thread">things</p></div>
```

I would like to match all the `things`. Knowing that `things` can be literally anything.

So, at first, I started with this regex: `/<div class\=\"thread\">(.*)<\/p><\/div>/` and I added a `/s` modifier to match the second line also.

Problem is, this regex only returns one match:

```
things</p></div><div class="thread">things</p></div>
<div class="thread">things
```

Because it starts at the first `<div class="thread">` and ends at the last `</p></div>`

**How could I instruct the regex to stop matching `.*` after the first `</p></div>`?**

Comment: You should be using a DOM parser if you expect the need to match anything more complex than this.

Comment: I tried to use a DOM parser, but I need to parse a 100mb file, and the parser doesn't like that quite much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may perhaps use the following *regex* ...

```
(?<=class="thread">).*?(?=<\/p>)
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ahg3L7/1)**

Answer (score 2):

Use `?` to make it "lazy". Refer [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for details

> ```
>  <div class\=\"thread\">(.*?)<\/p><\/div>/
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Make the regex non greedy:

```
regex: /<div class\=\"thread\">(.*?)<\/p><\/div>/
```

The `(.*?)` in the above regex says to match anything after the opening `<div>` tag until the *nearest* closing matching tag.

Your original regex was matching everything greedily until the *last* matching closing tags.

Comment: Thank you for your response!